# Create pop up for UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, popup

Hey! I have a UITableView with each row displaying a bunch of labels. I'd like to know if there is anyway to display a zoomed in version of my row as a pop up when a row is selected.

Answer (score 0):

use this and customize them as u needed

https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView